# slicing data for data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

[index size = 264 (1~24 * 11) , columns size = 8640](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4RpG.jpg)

There is a Float values in list data type sized 2279762.

I want to put values into dataframe but I don't know how to slice my values by 
264 each ..

I'm new to programming. could anyone give me any idea?

```
for n in range(264):
count += 1
para_num.append(count)
if count ==24 :
    count = 0     
df = pd.DataFrame(index=para_num, columns=time)
```

Comment: I uploaded the image for understanding

Comment: its not clear what you want could explain by example please...what you have and what you want